# SQL Server JBDC DATE gets wrong metadata result type

Tags: sql-server, date, jdbc

I have a strange problem:

When i create a column in SQL Server 2008, JDBC Driver 2.0, sqljdbc4.jar with Java 1.6

```
create table ctypes (dbms_date DATE NOT NULL, dbms_date_null DATE)
```

The data type in the database is correctly date

But when I access the table with JDBC select
The metadata says that the type is `nvarchar`, still the `getDate()` function is working. 
The problem is that I am programming a framework that generically copies data and must rely on the data type.

I am not a big SQL Server specialist, so maybe it some configuration in the SQL Server server that is responsible, I left as much to the default values as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed by downloading Driver 3.0